# atoi() method, char * cout II

Tags: c++, while-loop, char, compare

This is the **continnum** of [atoi() method, char * cout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15211507/atoi-method-char-cout)

The last question I don't understand is:

After line 5,

```
    while ( pCur >= pStr && *pCur <= '9' && *pCur >= '0' )     {
```

Now pCur = 2 and pStr = 242, why the condition is evaluated to be true?

I actually wrote the cout **test**:

```
    cout << "pCur: " << pCur << endl;       //line 5
    cout << "pStr: " <<  pStr << endl;  
    bool b = (pCur >= pStr);
    cout << "pCur >= pStr: " << b << endl;
```

**Output:**

```
pCur: 2    
pStr: 242
pCur >= pStr: 1
```

This doesn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pCur` and `pStr` are both `char*`. A `char*` is often understood as being a C-style string, because it might (and often does) point at the first character in a null-terminated array of `char`. When you do `cout << pCur`, the output stream `cout` interprets it as a C-style string and prints out the characters that it points at. If you want to print out the actual pointer values, try this:

```
cout << "pCur: " << static_cast<void*>(pCur) << endl;
cout << "pStr: " << static_cast<void*>(pStr) << endl;
```

The cast to a `void*` stops `cout` from treating it as a C-style string. I bet you'll now find that `pCur >= pStr` as expected.

Comment: Ohh I got it, but how does the compiler know what I meant to be pCur or static_cast<void*>(pCur)? In this while loop, the compiler seems to interpret it as static_cast<void*>(pCur) even though pCur was used

Comment: @HoKy22 Most everything you do to a `char*` will treat it as a pointer - because that's what it is. A `char*` really isn't special in any way. It's just a pointer. Some parts of the C++ library treat it differently. Most obviously, the input/output library has special overloads for functions to treat a `char*` as a C-style string.